# Problem in C with pointers, struct in struct and malloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have a problem with memory allocation in C and LVGL. The first part is the definitions.

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char Widgetcount;
    unsigned char index;
    lv_obj_t * btn[];
}AssetRADIOBUTTON;
typedef struct{

    lv_obj_t * tab;
    AssetRADIOBUTTON * Radio1;

}AssetSettingsSome;

typedef struct{
    
    lv_obj_t * ScreenMenuModule;
    unsinged char radioCOUNT;
    AssetSettingsSome Some;

}GUI_STRUCT_MODULES;
```

Now for initialization, if I call the memory allocation in subfunction, which works, in the subsubfunction with present code, it doesnt work.
Code which works:

```
void CreateRadioButton(AssetRADIOBUTTON * Radio,lv_obj_t * tab,unsigned char RadioCount)
{
   Radio->Widgetcount = RadioCount;
   for(unsigned char i=0;i<RadioCount;i++)
       Radio->btn[i] = lv_checkbox_create(tab);
   Radio->index = 0;
}
void CreateDialog(GUI_STRUCT_MODULES * Settings)
{
   Settings->radioCOUNT = 4;
   Settings->Some.Radio1 = malloc(sizeof(*Settings->Some.Radio1) + Settings->radioCOUNT * sizeof(*Settings->Some.Radio1->btn));
   CreateRadioButton(Settings->Some.Radio1,Settings->ECG.tab,4);
}
void main(void)
{
    static GUI_STRUCT_MODULES GUI_MODULES;
    CreateDialog(&GUI_MODULES);
}
```

Code Which doesnt work

```
void CreateRadioButton(AssetRADIOBUTTON * Radio,lv_obj_t * tab,unsigned char RadioCount)
{
    Radio = malloc(sizeof(*Radio) + RadioCount * sizeof(*Radio->btn));
    Radio->Widgetcount = RadioCount;
    for(unsigned char i=0;i<RadioCount;i++)
        Radio->btn[i] = lv_checkbox_create(tab);
    Radio->index = 0;
}
void CreateDialog(GUI_STRUCT_MODULES * Settings)
{
   CreateRadioButton(Settings->Some.Radio1,Settings->ECG.tab,4);
}
void main(void)
{
    static GUI_STRUCT_MODULES GUI_MODULES;
    CreateDialog(&GUI_MODULES);
}
```

Sorry for a bit long MVP.

Comment: C is pass by value; the argument `Radio` in `CreateRadioButton` is a local variable, and assigning to it has no effect on anything outside the function.  So the effect of `CreateRadioButton` is to allocate some memory, write some stuff to it, and then leak it, while `CreateDialog` sees `Settings->Some.Radio1` left unchanged by the call to `CreateRadioButton`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what is not working

```
void CreateRadioButton(AssetRADIOBUTTON * Radio, lv_obj_t * tab, unsigned char RadioCount)
{
    Radio = malloc(sizeof(*Radio) + RadioCount * sizeof(*Radio->btn));
```

You are storing the address of the allocated memory in `Radio`, which is a *local variable*. When you call `CreateRadioButton(Settings->Some.Radio1...)` you're just passing a pointer whose value you don't even look at. What you need to do, is tell your function where that pointer is, so it can be modified.

So, change the function signature so that it takes a pointer to a pointer, and pass the address of the pointer you want to change:

```
void CreateRadioButton(AssetRADIOBUTTON ** Radio,lv_obj_t * tab,unsigned char RadioCount)
{
    *Radio = malloc(sizeof(AssetRADIOBUTTON ) + RadioCount * sizeof(lv_obj_t));
    (*Radio)->Widgetcount = RadioCount;
    for(unsigned char i=0;i<RadioCount;i++)
        (*Radio)->btn[i] = lv_checkbox_create(tab);
    (*Radio)->index = 0;
}
...

CreateRadioButton(&Settings->Some.Radio1,Settings->ECG.tab,4);
```

Note the use of the `&` operator to get the *address of* the `Radio1` pointer, and in `CreateRadioButton` the use of the `*` operator to *dereference* the `Radio` pointer-to-pointer, to get a pointer-to-`AssetRADIOBUTTON`.

If this syntax is too cumbersome, consider the following alternative.

```
    AssetRADIOBUTTON* p = *Radio;
    p->Widgetcount = RadioCount;
    for(unsigned char i=0;i<RadioCount;i++)
        p->btn[i] = lv_checkbox_create(tab);
    p->index = 0;
```

This creates a new variable, but with any decent compiler the resulting code will be the same.

Comment: Now in this case, how can I access the contents of the Radio struct in CreateRadioButton? It says '*Radio' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?|

Comment: @vahidajal: by replacing that instance of `.` with `->`. The error told you exactly how to fix it.

Comment: There is no `.` in CreateRadioButton. All of them are `->` as you see. And this is surprising.

Comment: Please see my new edits. The arrow operator `->` is still the correct way to access a structure member from a pointer, but an additional `*` operator is needed to dereference the pointer-to-pointer back to a simple pointer.

Comment: I use Codeblocks and it does throw the error. Tried what you said recently before you say on my own, but no success.

Comment: Apologies. There was a problem with operator precedence that I'd missed.

Comment: Dear Tim Randall, Thank you. It works, but there is another problem, I can't figure out the concept, my basics of c seem insufficient. Would you please discuss this one? Or any keyword reference I can read?

Comment: @vahidajal I would look for "tutorial C++ pointer address dereference" and see where it leads me

Comment: Thank you Tim Randall, I was familiar with referencing, but wasn't aware of dereferencing.